# String format for plotting labels, but the entire string is given for legend entry

Tags: python, string, plot, format, legend

I have an array of integers that serve as identification for various dots on a graph.

```
k = [42., 64., 73., 31., 31., 31., 31., 2., 5., 16.]
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='name{}'.format(k))
plt.legend()
```

When I make the plot, the entire array of numbers is shown in the legend for each entry. What I need is each k-value labeled with its own x-y pair, as in (x[0], y[0]) and label(k[0]). How can I make the script stop showing the whole array for each label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like usable? I made some random x and y values and merged the data into Pandas DataFrame.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ---------------------
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd

k = [42., 64., 73., 31., 31., 31., 31., 2., 5., 16.]
x = np.random.random((np.size(k)));
y = np.random.random((np.size(k)));
# ----------------------------------------------
# let us have data collected to some object, that we can easily manipulate (e.g. Pandas DataFrame, dictionary...):
data = {'x':x,'y':y,'k':[int(vv) for vv in k]};
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data);df = df.set_index('k')
# ----------------------------------------------
for indval in set(df.index):
    plt.plot(df.loc[indval].x, df.loc[indval].y, 'o', label=indval,ms = 10)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```